# Need Help in deleting my duplicate account

Tags: support, status-completed

Unfortunately i tried to log in using my Facebook account, it created a duplicate stack overflow account because i have an account using yahoo, please delete the duplicate account
this is my original account
https://stackoverflow.com/users/424413/sankar-ganesh

this is the account created beacuse i have wrongly logged using facebook

https://stackoverflow.com/users/2572652/sankar-ganesh